# How to combine every two values in a nested list using Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists

```
nested_lst = [['AAA, CEO','BBB, Global Head','CCC, Regional Manager','DDD, Analyst','People also report to CCC','XXX, Analyst','VVV, Analyst'],
['AAA, CEO','BBB, Global Head','EEE, Regional Manager','FFF, Analyst','People also report to EEE','SSS, Analyst','LLL, Analyst'],
['AAA, CEO','BBB, Global Head','PPP, Regional Manager','MMM, Manager','People report to MMM','GGG, Associate','People also report to EEE','ZZZ, Junior Analyst','UUU, Contractor']]
```

Hi everyone,
I have a nested list shown above and I want to combine every two elements in that nested list. Desired output would be:

```
[['AAA, CEO & BBB, Global Head','BBB, Global Head & CCC, Regional Manager','CCC, Regional Manager & DDD, Analyst','DDD, Analyst & People also report to CCC',...],
['AAA, CEO & BBB, Global Head','BBB, Global Head & EEE, Regional Manager','EEE, Regional Manager & FFF, Analyst',...],
['AAA, CEO & BBB, Global Head','BBB, Global Head & PPP, Regional Manager',...]]
```

I tried `[' & '.join(x) for x in zip(nested_lst[2][0::2], nested_lst[2][1::2]) ]` but it didn't work for the nested list and didn't combine elements.

Can anyone help me with this question? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe:

```
result = [list(map(' & '.join, pairwise(l))) for l in nested_lst]
```

Or without itertools:

```
result = [list(map(' & '.join, zip(l, l[1:]))) for l in nested_lst]
```

Result:

```
[['AAA, CEO & BBB, Global Head', 'CCC, Regional Manager & DDD, Analyst', 'People also report to CCC & XXX, Analyst', 'VVV,Analyst'], ['AAA, CEO & BBB, Global Head', 'EEE, Regional Manager & FFF, Analyst', 'People also report to EEE & SSS, Analyst', 'LLL, Analyst'], ['AAA, CEO & BBB, Global Head', 'PPP, Regional Manager & MMM, Manager', 'People report to MMM & GGG, Associate', 'People also report to EEE & ZZZ, Junior Analyst', 'UUU, Contractor']]
```

Comment: Thank you Jab. The itertools.pairwise looks awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Your list comp is close. It needs a nested loop and a couple changes.

list_comp:

```
[[f'{x} & {y}' for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:])] for lst in nested_lst]

>>> output



[['AAA, CEO & BBB, Global Head',
 'BBB, Global Head & CCC, Regional Manager',
  'CCC, Regional Manager & DDD, Analyst',
  'DDD, Analyst & People also report to CCC',
  'People also report to CCC & XXX, Analyst',
  'XXX, Analyst & VVV, Analyst'],
 ['AAA, CEO & BBB, Global Head',
  'BBB, Global Head & EEE, Regional Manager',
  'EEE, Regional Manager & FFF, Analyst',
  'FFF, Analyst & People also report to EEE',
  'People also report to EEE & SSS, Analyst',
  'SSS, Analyst & LLL, Analyst'],
 ['AAA, CEO & BBB, Global Head',
  'BBB, Global Head & PPP, Regional Manager',
  'PPP, Regional Manager & MMM, Manager',
  'MMM, Manager & People report to MMM',
  'People report to MMM & GGG, Associate',
  'GGG, Associate & People also report to EEE',
  'People also report to EEE & ZZZ, Junior Analyst',
  'ZZZ, Junior Analyst & UUU, Contractor']]
```

Comment: Thank you, Brian. Your answer is super helpful!